# Maria DB storage capacity under Swisscom cloud

Tags: mariadb, galera, swisscomdev

According to this page https://developer.swisscom.com/pricing it is possible to define instances count for every plan. Does it mean that if I would need additional GBs for the system I would just need to add more instances and that's it? Nothing to change in code and I could use same connection parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this graph you see Apps (not services for persistent data). With apps you can add instances and memory very dynamically. Apps are stateless.

[image]

Please read [twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net) for more info about howto develop apps for CF.

> In the modern era, software is commonly delivered as a service: called
>   web apps, or software-as-a-service. The twelve-factor app is a
>   methodology for building software-as-a-service apps.

For services (with persistent data) you have to choose a plan. For example if you use `small` and you need more connections/storage (for example `large`), you can't upgrade with one command.

```
$ cf m -s mariadb
Getting service plan information for service mariadb as admin...
OK

service plan   description                                        free or paid
small          Maximum 10 concurrent connections, 1GB storage     paid
medium         Maximum 15 concurrent connections, 8GB storage     paid
large          Maximum 100 concurrent connections, 16GB storage   paid
```

You need to

- dump the database (use service connector plugin and `mysqldump` on local device)
- create a new service (`cf cs mariadb large ...`)
- restore data to new service (service connector and `mysql` client)
- delete old service (`cf ds -f...`)

There is no "one-click" upgrade at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Fyodor Glebov's answer:

There is an easy way towards one-click upgrades: Push2Cloud.

Using custom workflows you can automate every interaction with CloudFoundry. We provide two workflows/Docker Images that migrate Redis and MongoDB instances:

- [migrate-redis](https://github.com/push2cloud/migrate-redis/blob/master/README.md)
- [migrate-mongodb](https://github.com/push2cloud/migrate-mongodb/blob/master/README.md)

The same approach would also work for Maria DB. If you are interested in implementing the workflow, open an issue on the main Push2Cloud repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step guide for MongoDB:

1. Stop apps connected to old DB (to ensure data consistency)
2. Create service key for old mongodb (`cf create-service-key <mongodb-name> migration`)
3. Retrieve service key: `cf service-key <mongodb-name> migration`
4. `cf ssh` into any app in the same space as DB: `cf ssh <app-name> -L 13000:<mongodb-host>:<mongodb-port>` (host and port from service key)
5. The credentials for the following command can all be found in the service key you retrieved in step 3. **Open up a new terminal window** and run `mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:13000 --authenticationDatabase <mongodb-database> --username <mongodb-username> --password <mongodb-password> --db <mongodb-database> --out=dbbackup/dump`
6. Create new database with `cf create-service` (list available plans with `cf m -s mongodb`)
7. Create service key for new db and retrieve it
8. Close tunnel from above and create a new one with host and port from the new db
9. Run `mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1:13000 --authenticationDatabase <new-mongodb-database> --username <new-mongodb-username> --password <new-mongodb-password> --db <new-mongodb-database> <path-to-dump-file>`